# How to connect the selectionChanged signal with pyqt?

Tags: python, qgis, qgis-plugins

I am developing a plugin for QGIS in Python, I need to connect the sselectionChanged signal emitted when a feature of the layer is selected, I could not find any examples on internet, here is what I have done so far:

```
QObject.connect(self.iface.mapCanvas(),SIGNAL("selectionChanged(QgsMapLayer)"), self.test)
```

In the logs of QGIS I get this warning:

```
Warning: Object::connect: (receiver name: 'MainWindow')
```

can you help me?

Comment: Please post all relevant code lines.

Answer (score 5):

arpho, this [new style PyQt connection](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html) works for me in PyQGIS Console (Mac OS X 10.7.3, with QGIS 1.7.4)...

```
def test(layer): print "selection changed"

qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().selectionChanged.connect(test)
```

I had to hit return at an empty prompt to see the printed "selection changed" messages. If I changed the selection multiple times, those would show up upon hitting return.

The only thing I can see that might cause that error is if your 'self' object hasn't had the iface reference assigned. Is this in your __init__() method of your plugin's class?:

```
self.iface = iface
```

Or, that iface hasn't been passed to your plugin's class. Check your __ini__.py file for your plugin to make sure it's being passed as an argument to your plugin's class in the **def classFactory()** method.

Example:

```
def classFactory(iface):
    from my_plugin import MyPlugin
    return MyPlugin(iface)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi thanks for your answer; I did what you said in the python console of qgis and it works; I tried to make it work on my plugin.
 this  is an extract of my code:

```
def __init__(self, iface):
    # Save reference to the QGIS interface
    self.iface = iface
    self.tree=Tree()
    self.progressBar=ProgressBarWindow(True,True)
    self.progressBar.setMaximumOverall(4)
    self.ui_tree=MainWindowAlbero(iface)

def selectedChanged(self,t):
    self.ui_tree.etichetta.setText(t)

def run(self):
    self.iface.mapCanvas().selectionChanged.connect(self.selectedChanged("selected"))
```

when I launch the plugin I get this error

```
TypeError: connect() slot argument should be a callable or a signal, not 'NoneType'
```

why my function is a NoneType?> is not the first time I connect a signal to a method, I do not understand the problem

Comment: Your slot needs to be just a callable (i.e. `self.selectedChanged` instead of `self.selectedChanged("selected")`, note my example ). If you want to pass arguments (not necessary here) use lambda or the partial function module (examples online). The [selectionChanged signal](http://doc.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html#23fbdc9549eb365a6d063ee15efe3fa3) passes the QgsMapLayer that had a selection change. So, your slot should look like `selectedChanged(self, layer)`. If you want to get what's changed, in your slot test for layer type and get its selected features.

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing an asterisk (`*`) there.
It's `SIGNAL("selectionChanged(QgsMapLayer *)")` (notice the asterisk `*` after `QgsMapLayer`)

In C++ the asterisk refers to a pointer, and this is what the signal expects, compare http://qgis.org/api/2.4/classQgsMapCanvas.html#signals

Comment: I think you missed that this question is about Python, while your answer is about C++ …

Answer (score 0):

You can connect the selectionChanged signal emitted when a feature of the layer (in this case defined as class property and named **my_layer**) is selected like this:

```
QObject.connect(self.my_layer, SIGNAL("selectionChanged(const QgsFeatureIds&, const QgsFeatureIds&, const bool)"), self.test)
```

In class you also have to define associated method which has the same number of arguments (in this case 3):

```
def test(self, fselected, fdeselected, p):
```