# React to new selection with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I'm currently working on a QGIS plugin which uses the selected items of a vector layer containing only points. Using the current selection is quite easy but I need to react in real time to a change in the selection.

How can i do that without creating a custom selection tool. I haven't found anything in the developper cookbook or on google.

Comment: Connect a SLOT to this SIGNAL: https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ac32339abf885be1ed2262646e975dd87

Comment: possible duplicated https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/23457/49538

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the selectionChanged signal like mentionned in this post :

[How to define an event for features selected in mapcanvas in qgis using python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139823/how-to-define-an-event-for-features-selected-in-mapcanvas-in-qgis-using-python)

Comment: Thank you! Now I don't even know how I missed the whole signal part of the python API after the time I spent in it ^^'